# Blacklist and Whitelist on login

Tags: login, domain

I have an SSO login/registration and I need to have a blacklist for a certain domain @test.com, but, if needed, some users with same domain can enter for one day or two following clients requests.

Is there a clean way to do this thing with code or plugin? I've searched a lot of plugins but they only work with registration process and mainly work with IP. Website is closed to not-logged in users. With SSO I can't control Registration and most important thing many users land to website already registered. So I can only take fields that SSo system give to me (name - email)

At the moment I manually hide all content once user is logged in, but it's a manual method seraching in db all @test.com users. I need to automate this process.

Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a clean way to do this thing with code or plugin?

You will need to consult the documentation of the specific SSO integration you used as there is no general WordPress solution for your problem that does not involve code.

If code is an option, you could add a filter that checks the email and aborts with an error page instead, but you would need to construct the UI for the allowed/blocked lists yourself. There is also no guarantee that this won't interfere with your SSO solution.

As for plugins, blacklist plugins exist, but recommendations are off topic here